# Does the spell Line in the Sand work with the swashbuckler deed Opportune Parry and Riposte?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

The Swashbuckler's 1st-level deed [Opportune Parry and Riposte](https://www.aonprd.com/SwashbucklerDeeds.aspx#ctl00_MainContent_DataListTypes_ctl02_LabelName) states:

> Opportune Parry and Riposte (Ex): At 1st level, when an opponent makes
>   a melee attack against the swashbuckler, she can spend 1 panache point
>   and expend a use of an attack of opportunity to attempt to parry that
>   attack.

The description of the [*line in the sand*](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Line%20in%20the%20Sand) spell states:

> You create a glowing crimson line around the area. Against creatures
>   in the area, you can attempt a number of additional attacks of
>   opportunity per round equal to your spellcasting ability score
>   modifier (Intelligence for magi and wizards, Charisma for bloodragers
>   and sorcerers), although this does not allow you to make more than one
>   attack against a creature per action that provokes.

Can you make multiple parry-ripostes in the area of the spell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say **Yes**, but only to parry attacks that come from creatures in the spell's area (since otherwise you wouldn't have the extra AoOs to parry with).

The only difference between the text of Line in the Sand and Combat reflexes (besides the conditions for LitS and how the extra AoOs are calculated) is that LitS allows you to "attempt" extra AoOs and Combat Reflexes lets you "make" them. I don't consider that to be a meaningful distinction.

> Benefit: You may make a number of additional attacks of opportunity per round equal to your Dexterity bonus.

Since I have never seen someone argue that you shouldn't be able to parry with the AoOs granted by combat reflexes, it stands to reason that you should be able to parry with the extra AoOs from Line in the Sand, provided the positioning allows you to have them.